# VBA7 Compile Error Excel Windows 7

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose I have a custom library (.dll) called;
    Library.dll

Within the library, there is a class called;
    class

I generate an object called testObject:

```
Dim testObject As New Library.Class
```

There is a function called testFunction:

```
Function testFunction(var1 As Double, var2 As Double, var3 As Double, var4 As Double, _
var5 As Double, var6 As Integer, var7 As Double, var8 As Double, var9 As Double)
    Call testSetup(var1, var2, var3, var4, var6, var7, var8, var9)
    testFunction = testObject.Field(var5)
End Function
```

This function calls testSetup:

```
Sub testSetup(var1 As Double, var2 As Double, var3 As Double, var4 As Double, _
var5 As Double, var6 As Integer, var7 As Double, var8 As Double, var9 As Double)
    testObject.Lat1 = var1
    testObject.Lon1 = var2
    testObject.Lat2 = var3
    testObject.Lon2 = var4
    testObject.mth = var6
    testObject.GMT = var7
    testObject.ssn = var8
    testObject.icf = var9
End Sub
```

The problem I have is that upon running, if I place a break point at the location

```
testObject.Lat1 = var1
```

Upon running and stepping over to the next line, if I hover over the object

```
testObject.Lat1
```

I see the error

**object variable or With block variable not set**

There is NO Crash and no explicit error message causing a fail.

Anyone have any ideas?

I'm not sure if the error is within the library or the code?

Also it's run from excel by typing into a cell
    =testFunction(var1, var2, var3....)

**Edit: More info in comments**

Comment: Whats the scope of testObject  ?

Comment: what do you mean by scope? Thx

Comment: Please declare testObject at moudle level or public.

Comment: sorry, I don't really understand what you mean?  I've declared `testObject As Library.Class` up the top of the code and then `set testObject = New Library.Class` in the `sub testSetup`

Comment: link for you : http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solution has been found.  It wasn't due to errors in the code, the

```
Dim testObject As New Library.Class
```

worked fine.

As does

```
Dim testObject As Library.Class
```

followed by

```
Set testObject = New Library.Class
```

The problem was that in VB, I registered the library dll file through

```
Tools > References
```

I assumed this would be enough as I didn't have admin rights.

I was wrong.

I needed to log in as Administrator and thern register the dll using

```
regsvr32 ".dll path"
```

Now i'm seeing sensible outputs in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

In VBA you can initiate an object via two methods:

1. `Dim o as New Object`
2. `Dim o as Object: Set o = New Object`

The difference is that in version one the object is initiated *the first time it is access in the code*! (Note: This is different to VB.NET). In the second case it gets initiated explicitly when your run the `Set o = New Object`.

Therefore, when you set your breakpoint in the line `testObject.Lat1 = var1`, testObject is actually not yet allocated and the debugger can therefore not access anything! Only after executing this line will you see a result.

If this bothers you, you simply need to add

```
Set testObject = new Library.Class
```

Comment: If I place the breakpoint at the location 'Call testSetup', then I see the same thing when I step into the Sub and then over the 'testObject.lat1 = var1'.  Does this fit with your solution?

Comment: Also, I'm using VBA7 within Excel 2010, if that changes anything

Comment: yes - only after the testObject was accessed for the first time (which is somewhere in testSetup it'll be visible in the debugger (unless you use `Set ... = New ...` as described). This also applies to VBA7!

Comment: so I can replace `Dim testObject As New Library.Class` with `Dim testObject as Library.Class`.  And then within testSetup, the first line could by `set testObject = New Library.Class`.  I'll try this asap

Comment: @user2111939 : if you use Dim testObject As New LibraryClass then testObject is Nothing until it if used for the first time. So If (testObject Is Nothing) Then ... will never be True bacause the 'Is Nothing' test will create the object :-).

Comment: @DanielDusek: Good point, I didn't think of that! Adjusted the answer.

Comment: Right, i've tried this just now and have the following comments.  As I step through the, `sub testSetup`, once I step over the line I have just inserted, `set testObject = New Library.Class', the execution simply stops, and I receive no error message.  Does this imply there is something wrong with the library.class part?  It seems like testObject just isn't being set correctly.

Comment: More info:  This all used to work fine on 32bit version of Excel 2010 on a Windows XP Machine.  I'm running this version on Windows 7, also with a 32bit version of Excel 2010.  If that helps narrow anything down.